# Should I never use stdbuf's fully buffered mode?

Tags: coreutils

On my system (a recently updated Arch Linux), the manpage for `stdbuf` has the following in the "BUGS" section:

> On GLIBC platforms, specifying a buffer size, i.e., using fully buffered mode will result in undefined operation.

Apart of being mildly curious why this is the case and what 'undefined operation' means, I'm mostly worried whether or not that means that I should never specify buffer sizes for the command, and whether or not it can explode in my face if I do.

Comment: "Undefined" means, just that.  Anything could happen, including nasal demons flying out of your nose - http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html :-)

Comment: You can read an explanation in a [comment](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/4711c49312d54e84996c13c612f7081c95f821a6/src/libstdbuf.c#L28) from stdbuf's source.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks for the link, it is most helpful! Do I understand it correctly that it means that no actual undefined behaviour is involved, but the command will simply have no effect?

Comment: The only 'undefined behavior' was that glibc was deciding the buffer size itself when allocating the buffer, instead of honoring the size given via `setvbuf`. But this a) doesn't seem to affect `stdbuf` anymore, see answer b) wasn't nasal daemon material in the 1st place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that's just a left-over from a previous version of `stdbuf`, and does not correspond to the reality anymore.

In a [comment](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/4711c49312d54e84996c13c612f7081c95f821a6/src/libstdbuf.c#L28) from `stdbuf`'s source code, it says that:

> ```
> /* Note currently for glibc (2.3.5) the following call does not change
>    the buffer size, and more problematically does not give any indication
>    that the new size request was ignored:
>        setvbuf (stdout, (char*)NULL, _IOFBF, 8192);
> ```

But the actual code goes on and (reluctantly?) allocates the 
buffer itself instead of relying on the C library to do it, completely bypassing that problematic behavior.

> ```
>       if (size > 0)
>         {
>           if (!(buf = malloc (size))) /* will be freed by fclose()  */
> ```

Also this (from the same comment) doesn't seem to be the case anymore:

> ```
>    Another issue is that on glibc-2.7 the following doesn't buffer
>    the first write if it's greater than 1 byte.
>        setvbuf(stdout,buf,_IOFBF,127);
> ```

No matter what arguments I give to the `-i` and `-o` options, it seems to handle them fine. Example:

```
$ echo 'int main(){ int c; while((c=getchar()) != EOF) putchar(c); }' | cc -include stdio.h -x c - -o slowcat
$ strace -s5 -e trace=read,write stdbuf -i143 -o127 2>&1 ./slowcat </dev/zero >/dev/null | awk '/ELF/{next}1;++n>5{exit}'
read(0, "\0\0\0\0\0"..., 143)           = 143
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0"..., 127)          = 127
read(0, "\0\0\0\0\0"..., 143)           = 143
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0"..., 127)          = 127
read(0, "\0\0\0\0\0"..., 143)           = 143
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0"..., 127)          = 127
```